# I got error "app record creation failed as you do not have permission to perform request of this type." when trying to upload the archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I tried to upload the app previously its was working fine I uploaded around 17 builds to testflight but recently we converted to Organization account and I was assigned the admin role and since then I am unable to upload.
Xcode version 14.2
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/920Pt.png)

I have tried removing and adding the app store id.
I ahve also tried changing name and bundle identifier.

Comment: Check if there is no agreement to validate on AppStore Connect.

Comment: The agreements are active

Comment: Please avoid posting error messages as images. Edit the title of the question to include the error message to improve discoverability.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the new app with same bundle identifier on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/, which solved my issue. Initially I was trying to upload from Xcode whereas my application was not there on Appstore connect.